# What share price to use to calculate forecast accuracy?

Tags: equities, research

I've been reading about models like Thiel's-U but I can't figure out what I should use for the actual trading price.

The dilemma is this: the analyst reports I’m looking at are forecasting for 12-18 months into the future. I considered just adding 15 (average of 12 and 18) months to whenever the report was published and comparing their price target to the closing price on that single day (i.e., June 1, 2001 compared to September 1, 2002). But this seems to have a very small margin of error and is susceptible to abnormal trading days.

I also considered using a 6-month running average centered at 15 months after the report (i.e., the report from June 1, 2001 compared to the average price from June 1, 2002 to December 1, 2002). This seems like a much better option, but I wanted to know if there was already some established practice that I'm missing here.

Comment: Don't delete and create the same question again please. Bumping your question like this is not tolerated.

Comment: Can’t give you a recommendation on what to do but I sense a problem with your premises. Equity research target prices, if for the next 12- or 18-months, are not exactly forecasts of future prices. They are usually based on what the analyst thinks the company's equity is worth today given _today’s_ interest rates, comparable multiples, etc. The future target price is, then, arrived simply by inflating today's fair price by the company’s estimated cost of equity or multiplying earnings, etc. by a slightly higher multiple than the currently prevailing.